# Redirect console progress percentage to Form

Tags: c#

I'm building a batch processing GUI around [rtmpdump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/) and I'd like to redirect the progress percentage that is outputted in the console window to a `ProgressBar` control.

Is this in any way possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you launch console app from winForms app?

Comment: You'll probably need to use a separate thread to read the output.  If your main thread is waiting for output from the console task then it won't be responding to any other GUI events.

Comment: Yes, the console app is launched from within the winForm.

Comment: I am running into the same problem.  None of the output is given to WinForm application until after the last WriteLine in the console.  I am assuming the console application is using Console.Write("/r {Some Progress}"); So it over writes the previous progress.  I can't find a way to intercept that Console.Write

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output stream of a console application that you launch as a child of a WinForms process.

If the console output contains information you can use to derive the percent complete, you can then use that to update your ProgressBar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx